# Regex in String

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a keylogger , with an intent of just getting the float numbers from keyboard input and with them compute some formula and display to the user. My code so far (the HookCallBack part)

```
 private static IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {

            string xxx = "";
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);   


                if (((Keys)vkCode).ToString() == "OemPeriod")
                {
                    //Console.Out.Write(".");
                    xxx += ".";
                    xxx.Replace("OemPeriod", ".");
                }
                if (((Keys)vkCode).ToString() == "D1")
                {
                    //Console.Out.Write(".");
                    xxx += "1";
                    xxx.Replace("D1", "1");
                }
                if (((Keys)vkCode).ToString() == "D2")
                {
                    //Console.Out.Write(".");
                    xxx += "2";
                    xxx.Replace("D2", "2");
                }
```

all the way up to 9 and 0

```
                }
                if (((Keys)vkCode).ToString() == "Space")
                {
                    //Console.Out.Write(".");
                    xxx += " ";
                    xxx.Replace("Space", " ");
                }


            }


            string test = "2.3 4.5 6.7";   

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d+");
            var ma2 = regex.Matches(xxx);
            Console.Out.Write(ma2.Count);

            xxx = String.Empty;      

            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

My issue is this: im not able to make the regex to work (ma2.Count = 0) with the string xxx (which is the keyboard input from the user), but when i replace xxx with the string test, it works. What im doing wrong. Dont know if i was clear enough. Newbie here. Thks in advance!

Comment: Did you try debugging and watching the value of `xxx` after every step?

Comment: Why do you `xxx.Replace("D1", "1");` ? There is no way a D1 is able to enter XXX as your code currently stands ... same for all others. Why do you excplicitly match all - you could simply have a hashset of allowed key-Code-Names. Use a switch and handle D0-D9 the same: add the last character of the keycodename - handle space and dot as is.

Comment: OT instead of checking `if (((Keys)vkCode).ToString() == "OemPeriod")`, you can omit the (relatively expensive) .ToString and string match, and just check `if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.OemPeriod)`

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

It looks like this method is being called every time a new key is being called, however, you are updating a local variable called `xxx`.

Every time this method gets invoked, you are always starting with an empty string. At most, `xxx` will have 1 character.

You will need store the value of `xxx` outside the scope of the function.

Not recommended (because you want to avoid `static` variables for this type of thing), but you could introduce a new variable:

```cs
private static string InputFields = "";
```

and use `InputFields += ".";` for example.

Also note that `xxx.Replace(...)` doesn't actually do anything here because you are not assigning the result of this method to anything. You can drop it altogether.

---

As per @CinCout's comment, are you able to verify the value of `xxx`?

I tried the example above and it should work with the `test` input:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = "2.3 4.5 6.7";
        var regex = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d+");
        var matches = regex.Matches(test);

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OZ2qQc)

Comment: OP confirmed that the test input works. OP is having trouble getting it to work with `xxx`, likely because `xxx` is never longer than 1 character due to it being reset to an empty string every time HookCallback is called

Comment: Sorry... missed that part